# Quick and dirty slow motion effects?

Tags: sound-design, sfx, television

I'm starting to work on a show, that has a ton of slow-motion shots (I mean a ton), in every kind of situation.

Since I have to do an episode a day (50 minutes of program), do you guys have some sort of plug in chain or effects that are your go to?

At this point I'm going with reverb (mostly waves Rverb) vary-fi, pitch, and good old low pass.

We don't have any time stretch plug in that I like, and work flow with paul stretch is to slow for this, though I love it.

I would just stretch a bunch of files with paulstretch to have them handy, but like I said, its used in just about any situation, so that is not very practical.

The plugs we have are the protools native most of waves plugs and some sonnox stuff.

Any tips are appreciated :)